# Collaborative online photo gallery

Tags: web-apps, photography, multi-user

I am looking for a collaborative online photo gallery platform. I need the following features:

- Create one main event/page/topic
- Users can upload multiple photos to this event/page/topic. They can add their name and a short description of their collection
- The service should be for free
- Users should not have to register an account
- Intuitive interface that also unexperienced users can use to easily upload photos

The closest services that I have found are [DropEvent](http://www.dropevent.com) and [padlet.com](http://padlet.com). Padlet is almost perfect. It offers one canvas where users can add their post-it with their name and a short description. However, it allows users to upload only one photo. I do not want users having to create multiple post-its but one collection of photos.

Do you know any online service that suits my needs?