# Online photo SHARING APP to show my album pictures on map based on EXIF GPS data

Tags: web-apps, photography, maps

I went on a hike, took a bunch of geotagged pictures, and I want to upload them and have them displayed on a map. What photo sharing services support displaying imagines from a specific user's album on a map? Bonus points if a path (itinerary) can be drawn.

What I've tried so far:

- Flickr - [works - see example](https://www.flickr.com/photos/danvdascalescu/sets/72157644669826464/map/). *WARNING*: doesn't read geolocation data from the EXIF header unless you go to the [Flickr privacy and permissions settings](https://www.flickr.com/account/privacy/) and set "Hide your EXIF data" to `No` **and also** "Import EXIF location data" to `Yes`, and "Who will be able to see your stuff on a map" to `anyone`. Donwsides: torturous interface, uploads time out. Upsides: backed by Yahoo!, large community, 1TB free storage.
- Picasa - no maps, despite being owned by Google
- Panoramio (also owned by Google) - your photos must be approved to get on the map. Even then, I have [32 photos approved](http://www.panoramio.com/user/6305660/stats), but none show up on [my map](http://www.panoramio.com/map/?user=6305660#lt=37.804045&ln=-122.416244&z=2&k=1&a=1&tab=4&pl=all).
- Fotki - Reads EXIF GPS data but shows *all* of your photos on a map. Can't show a particular album. Also, you can't download the originals of your photos, apparently.
- Facebook - no maps

It's a bit puzzling that as of 2014, it's so hard to find a service like this, and that the major players don't seem to be offering one.

Comment: You tagged your question web-apps. Do you want to avoid offline tools? I remember from Panoramio that you can download a file for Google Earth, and you can always watch your own pictures on the map.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software*, not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: @Izzy: That meta post specifically discusses _hosting_. This question sounds more web service / app to me and I thought web services were on topic for this site? [Are web service recommendations off-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-web-service-recommendations-off-topic)

Comment: @Izzy: I've already been [reprimanded for posting this on WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60568/what-online-photo-storage-can-map-pictures-based-on-exif-gps-data#comment48550_60568). Can you please take up the issue with @jonsca?

Comment: You are incorrect about Flickr - it does read coordinates from the EXIF data. I often upload geotagged photos to Flickr, this works fine.

Comment: @vclaw: [this photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/danvdascalescu/13987142450/in/set-72157644635945422) is geotagged (Fotki has read its info correctly) but on Flick I don't see any location information.

Comment: Check your [Flickr privacy and permissions settings](https://www.flickr.com/account/privacy/) You need to make sure the option for "Import EXIF location data" is set to yes. And also set "Hide your EXIF data" to no, and "Who will be able to see your stuff on a map" to anyone.

Comment: Arg. I *had* set "Hide" to "no" and the map visibility to "anyone" from some photo option when uploading them, and thought that was enough, but didn't dig into the privacy settings to find the "Import" one (which wasn't present when I imported the photos). Now I need to re-upload everything...

Comment: @w3d The question title explicitly states *Online photo storage*, which implies hosting. It might include a web app, but that's then bound to the hosting service. To my understanding, web apps simply means that the *app* is running on a web service. Admitted, borders might be a bit hard to define here; but asking for online storage IMHO definitely makes it a hosting question.

Comment: @Izzy: storage is incidental. All the services I've already researched provide storage but what I care about is the ability to display maps online within a web app.

Comment: @Izzy: here's [one more question for you to ban](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/collaborative-online-photo-gallery)

Comment: I'm assuming you know this but iPhones have had this feature for years.