# Webapp to view GPS track and photos on map

Tags: web-apps, photography, maps, gps

I'm looking for web service for sharing gps track (any format) and photos with gps info - оn the same map. Like in Google Earth.

I know http://everytrail.com has such feature, but photos downscaled much.

Comment: Duplicate of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4067/online-photo-sharing-app-to-show-my-album-pictures-on-map-based-on-exif-gps-data