# How can I view my photos on a map on desktop?

Tags: photography, maps

The Google Photos app for Android has a feature where you can view photos on a map. Photos appear as icons on the map, based on where they were taken.

Unfortunately the Google Photos website does not offer this feature.

I am aware of this question: [Online photo SHARING APP to show my album pictures on map based on EXIF GPS data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4067/online-photo-sharing-app-to-show-my-album-pictures-on-map-based-on-exif-gps-data)
That's about web apps. I am happy to use a desktop app.

How can I view my photo collection on a map, on a desktop computer (Windows based, or Linux via WSL)?

Comment: What about view images on the map one by one? Also are you ready to pay subscription?

Comment: I want to see all the photos I have taken on the map. I might pay for it if the offer is good, but would prefer a free option, not least because if it's say open source there is no chance of it being withdrawn at some point.

Comment: What OS should the solution run on – and is there a price margin to stay within?

Comment: Windows, ideally free but I'll consider paid options if they add enough subjective value.

Answer (score 1):

The product I have in mind is commercial - Adobe Lightroom. It is quite long time on the market and I do not see any signs to disappear.

But will cost you 120USD/140Euro annually.

And mapping is only small part of the features you have. It is very powerful editor for photos.

Here is how the interface looks like:
[image]

P.S. If you can find for download Picasa you can do this there too.

Answer (score 0):

Geo-Setter can do this: https://geosetter.de/en/main-en/

You can view images as markers on a map, within the app. It can also display tracks (recorded sets of GSP coordinates).

Unfortunately it does appear to be abandoned, but it works for now.

digiKam also has this feature, but you can't click on the thumbnails to display the actual images.